# Struts2 sending array text input to Action

Tags: arrays, forms, struts2, action

I have a form with some input fields with the same name in order to send an array of values to the action.

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" value="apple"/>
<input type="text" name="myInput" value="banana"/>
<input type="text" name="myInput" value="grapefruit"/>
```

Now in the action I have the parameter set with getter and setter. I tried various things:

```
String myInput
String[] myInput
List<String> myInput
List myInput
```

Nothing works, the value is always null. I tested using String and sending 1 value only, that works as expected, but the array isn't getting anywhere.

@Aleksandr

I'm sending the form using POST method.

Action is quite simple:

```
<action name="save" class="com.mypackage.SaveAction">
    <result name="success">/saveSuccess.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Show action configuration. How do you submit values?

Comment: Edited the original post with more info

Comment: It should just work. :) Are you using some custom interceptor stack instead of default one?

Comment: Which one should work? String[]? I have an upload interceptor but not for this action, using it in another action.

Comment: Package extends some defaults in struts, might that be the problem? -> <package name="Intra" namespace="/Intra" extends="struts-default,hibernate-default,json-default">

Comment: Well, ALL of them should work.

Comment: Wow...this looks like a problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you sure you have appropriate getters and setters?

Comment: Yeah. If i set String myInput, and in the form only put 1 value instead of multiple, the action reads it with no problems.

Comment: Which version of Struts2? Examine what is being submitted in dev tool network tab. If you have multiple inputs do you see that values are being sent?

Comment: Values are all being send. Could it be that it is too much data? Cause my array is really really big. I thought in POST there is no problem with big data.

Comment: It could be. Try with simple/short values, like in your question.

Comment: Define "really really big".

Comment: With short values it's working, so it must be size. In this case my text load is about 8mb...

Comment: Out of curiosity. What data you are sending?

Comment: 8mb through input fields: [wat](http://triggerplug.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/6ab.jpeg)

Comment: To make it short it's json data i'm putting through pages. It's to integrate data into a database. CSV rows get associated to the id found in the db (through a unique individual code, somewhat like the social number in the US). Once associated i have name and id of the person, and i'm putting through pages the rows with its ids (and like it happened this time it can be some k rows). I wanted to avoid reading the file multple times. I guess i'll need to change to ajax processing a few rows at once instead of doing all at once.

Comment: The problem arouse when the hidden input cut off a part of the json string. So i tried splitting it up.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yeah initially it was designed to receieve some hundred of rows, and that worked but "fortunately" (so I'll have a job for a long time I hope :P) the project has grown bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this to answer my question.

In the end it seems like the size of the request was too big.